# How to tell docker-compose exec to read from stdin?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

`docker-compose exec` is failing when reading from `stdin`:

```
$ echo "use mydb; show measurements;" | docker-compose exec influxdb influx
Connected to http://localhost:8086 version 1.2.4
InfluxDB shell version: 1.2.4
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('docker-compose==1.9.0', 'console_scripts', 'docker-compose')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 65, in main
    command()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 117, in perform_command
    handler(command, command_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 462, in exec_command
    pty.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dockerpty/pty.py", line 338, in start
    io.set_blocking(pump, flag)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dockerpty/io.py", line 32, in set_blocking
    old_flag = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
ValueError: file descriptor cannot be a negative integer (-1)
```

Using the `-T` flag gets rid of the problem, but it seems to suppress reading from stdin:

```
$ echo "use mydb; show measurements;" | docker-compose exec -T influxdb influx
```

(I need to kill that command, since it shows nothing and is not able to read from `stdin`)

This seems like a `docker-compose` bug, maybe I should file this?

```
$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.9.0, build 2585387
```

### EDIT

Related:

- https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3352
- https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4290

Answer (score 6):

In https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3352 endzyme suggests using the `docker` command for doing this. I created a tiny bash function I have in my bash profile based on his suggestion:

```
# Like `docker-compose exec` but forwarding stdin to the container
# See https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3352
function docin() {
  local service="$1"; shift
  docker exec -i "$(docker-compose ps -q $service)" "$@"
}
```

In your case you would use it like:

```
echo "use mydb; show measurements;" | docin influxdb influx
```

It's a good enough work-around until they fix this in `docker-compose`.